# Arthur and co prime program Coprime Conundrum not getting the desired output

Tags: java, algorithm

I am writing one java program. Arthur defines a function `f(k)` to be the number of `(p,q)` pairs such that:

- `1< p <= q <= k`
- p and q are coprimes
- p.q=k

I am supposed to write one program for a given integer `n` and help Arthur find and print the result of `(Σ k=1 to n) f(k)`

Constraints: 
`1<=n<=pow(10,9)`

For e.g

(Input)Let's say `n = 12`
For the value of `f(k)` for `1<=k<=12`
For `k=6` there is one valid pair `(2,3)`, so `f(6) = 1`
For `k=10` there is one valid pair `(2,5)`, so `f(10) = 1`
For `k=12` there is one valid pair `(3,4)`, so `f(12) = 1`
For all other 1<=k<=12 the function return 0
So, other final sum is the result of `1+1+1 = 3` (**Final output**)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArthurFunction{
    public static boolean areCoPrime(int a, int b){
        int max = 0;
        boolean flag = true;
        if(a>=b)
            max = a;
        else
            max = b;
        for(int i=2;i<=max;i++)
            if((a%i==0)&&(b%i==0))
                flag = false;
        return flag;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        for(int k = 1;k<=n;k++){
            for(int p=2;p<=k;p++){
                for(int q=2;q<=k;q++){
                    if(areCoPrime(p,q)&&(p*q==k)&&(p<=q))
                        sum+=sum;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

When I run this code the output should be `3` but I am getting `0` and also unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your program by

1. Making a faster `areCoPrime()` method
2. Decrease the number of nested loops in `main()`

For (1), we know 2 numbers are coprime when their greatest common divisor (GCD) is 1. Their is an efficient method to find GCD called Euclidean algorithm.

For (2), you can remove the 3rd loop, `p` in the 2nd loop only need to go to `sqrt(k)`

Refer to my revised code below (**Tested:** n = pow(10,6) runs less than 2 secs on my PC)

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class ArthurFunction{

public static boolean areCoPrime(int a, int b){
    if (GCD(a,b)==1) return true;
    return false;
}
public static int GCD(int a, int b) {
       if (b==0) return a;
       return GCD(b,a%b);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    for(int k=1;k<=n;k++){          
        for(int p=2;p*p<k;p++){      
            if(k%p==0) {                    
                int q = k/p;                    
                if (areCoPrime(p,q)) sum++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
}
```